# Source and drain of a transistor

Tags: electricity

Sorry for this question but it's really confusing me everytime I want to solve the equations of transistors.

The professor told us that in NMOS, the source is the small voltage, and the drain is the biggest voltage(they are interchangeable).

My question:

Lets assume I have already vdd in one of two diode of n+ , then how we assume that the other diode of n+ is the source? Because maybe the other diode n+ has voltage vdd(so both diode of transistor having voltage vdd), then how do we decide which one is the source?

I'm getting confused everytime !

Comment: This doesn't make any sense!

Comment: why?! I know it doesn't make any sense! but how can I define the process of choosing when I have drain and when I have source?!

Comment: Does 'diode of n+' mean one of the n+ doped terminals, i.e. electrodes?   Diode means a two-electrode ensemble.

Answer (score 6):

For a planar 4-terminal NMOS transistor there is no required **physical** difference between the source and the drain. However, for the channel to conduct we require that the voltage from gate to **source** be greater than the threshold voltage, and the voltage at the **drain** can be higher than the gate voltage. So, to be consistent with the definition of "threshold voltage" we must declare that the terminal with the lower voltage is the **source**. For a PMOS transistor the source will be the terminal with the higher voltage.

Now, for 3-terminal MOSFETs the body is usually connected to one terminal and that terminal becomes the **source**. It must be at a lower voltage during normal operation or the body-drain junction will become forward biased.

Comment: @Ryan Glad it helped. If you ask a question on this site and the answer helps you, the suggested way to thank someone is to "accept" the answer.

Comment: I've always thought that thanking someone is, itself, thanking them. This isn't like tipping a waitress. Accepting an answer is for saving the time of others who might imagine adding another answer if one is already fine. That's got nothing to do with the answerer. That's about everyone else's time. (That may be important here. No question. But it's a different thing.) To me? The thanks are wonderful and more than enough!! Everything that matters. It's great you helped Ryan! The point system is just silliness. If it didn't exist, I'd be happy.

Answer (score 4):

The channel of a MOSFET (Source <--> Drain) is just that... a channel. *One* channel.

The *Gate* voltage (with respect to whatever Source is), controls how much that *channel* (S <--> D) conducts.

As far as whether S or D can be more positive, either can, and it doesn't matter. What matters is the Gate-Source voltage. That voltage is what opens or closes the channel.  The channel is nothing more than a variable resistance, controlled by VGS.

MOSFETs are often found in typical configurations, such as an enhancement-mode NMOS with the Source tied to ground. Don't let that fool you into thinking that the Source *must*  always be more negative than the Drain. Those are wired that way because they are easier to drive the gate.

Comment: To correctly specify \$V_{GS}\$ it **is** necessary (for NMOS) to stipulate that the source is the more negative pin. I think a better way to describe it, so the definitions and equations make sense, is that the source is the terminal at the lower voltage. I'm assuming a 4-terminal MOSFET, of course.